# how to get the value of an object in java which is used for attlassian jira

Tags: java, jira

I have `getIssue()` method in jira that returns a HashMap as output. I want the value held in the `affectsVersions` object as output. But I am getting an exception. `getIssue()` is an rpc-xml method

```
HashMap<String,String> result = (HashMap<String,String>) rpcClient.execute("jira1.getIssue", issueVector);
String ver = (String) result.get("affectsVersions");
System.out.println(ver);
```

Output:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: does `rpcClient.execute("jira1.getIssue", issueVector)` return `HashMap<String,String>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The affectsVersions field is returning an array of objects, not a single String (since an issue can have multiple Affects Versions).

In line 2, you want to write:

```
Object[] affectsVersions = (Object[])result.get("affectsVersions");
```

...and then iterate through the array as needed.